# Has the universe been rearranged?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

In the new DLC for X3: Terran Conflict, are there any changes to the overall layout of the universe in terms of gate connections or neighboring sector placement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CBJ, a big boy at Egosoft, has [posted here](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=311327) a pretty lengthy guide detailing the new features of Albion Prelude. It is a good read, and has made me consider pausing Skyrim (blasphemous!). However, he only has this to say about the new map:

> Map
>
> Albion
>
> Albion is a key area of space that will feature heavily in X Rebirth.
>   You can get your first glimpses of Albion in X3: Albion Prelude, and
>   see emerging signs of the momentous changes that new technology will
>   bring to the X Universe. Look out for the corporations that are
>   driving this new technology and vying for control of the new sectors
>   and the valuable resources they contain.
>
> Other
>
> The X Universe is a dynamic place, and even in the short time since
>   X3: Terran Conflict some things have changed. New space has been
>   discovered, control of some sectors has been lost by the people who
>   once lived there, and in a few cases gates have mysteriously shut down
>   cutting off routes that were once busy thoroughfares. We won't be
>   spoiling the fun for explorers, however, by giving precise details
>   about what has changed!

And I found a quick 'initial-glance' list from [EmperorJon](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=311655&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0)

> Universe Changes -
>
> Many of your familiar Unknown Sectors have been
>   claimed. Some more have appeared. The North East of the universe is
>   different! Zyarth's Dominion no longer links to Ocean of Fantasy, the
>   Split sector in between them is GONE! It's a dead end Split area up
>   there. Sector descriptions suggest they're trapped and the gates are
>   beginning to fail as the Xenon advance. Bluish Snout now links to 4 of
>   the "player sectors". Xenon Core 023 now links through to Xenon
>   sectors connected to Aldrin! So Heretic's End isn't the ONLY way to
>   the Solar System... Wink Harmony of Perpetuity is included, and owned
>   by the Goners.

It is definitely a big improvement on TC, and [should certainly give fun until TNBT comes along.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=LabrDe4XJo0)

To quote Gazz, the legendary author of MARS and many other scripts:

> No revolution but a lot of evolution. =)

EDIT: And you can now have a balance of 2,000,000,000,000,000,000 credits, not 2B :D

Comment: wow, that sounds awesome.  I have to admit I DID put down Skyrim for this DLC, but I haven't explored much yet :)

Comment: I'm out of votes till the reset, I'll up tick you then.

Comment: hmm, reading the stuff to answer the question has persuaded me. Betty has been silent for too long!

Comment: I haven't regretted my choice yet, I've put in a few hours into it yesterday.  The environment is MUCH more entertaining, so many more military presence everywhere.  I wrote a short blog about it which should go up in the next few days on our blog site.

Comment: yeah. I am really excited at being able to construct a corp easily without spending 20 hours placing 300 stations in a sector with my laptop slowing to 2 frames per second. I will not miss those sessions!! It sounds like it will be a more rapid-paced gameplay, which is great for a prelude as it gives a chance to play around before the main event.